# Safely and efficiently evaluate simple string to query .NET POCO

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I am writing an app in ASP.NET to be run in Azure Websites that gets some JSON and returns a value out of it based on user input.  For example:

```
dynamic json = GetSomeJSONAndParseToDynamicClass();
var userInput = "somefield.somearray[20].somefield";
var output = GetValueFromObject(json,userInput);
```

In the above example, what is the best way to implement "GetValueFromObject"?  I can think of a couple possibilities, but am unsure of all of them:

- Parse the user input string - split on '.' and '[n]', then use that to evaluate the query.
- Use some script engine to evaluate the expression.
- Convert to XML and parse as XPath

Is there anything in .NET natively to do this, or a good library to get this sort of functionality?

Comment: It seems to me like this would require a lot of tricky reflection and parsing to accomplish, and isn't something you'd want to try to roll yourself. Have you considered using something [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) or [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/)?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with CS-Script, but those have possibilities.  I guess I worry that 1) a scripting engine is too 'heavy' and 2) users may send in malicious input.  I should qualify: this is an ASP.NET app running in Azure Websites...

Comment: @Daniel if you want it really lightweight (just member access or index access) it is not that hard to write it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same requirements as what you're listing, and I ended up having to write my own macro-parsing utility that only allows accessing properties and indexers. Then I make sure that this is only ever passed a "base object" that is intended for this purpose. (We put this special class of POCOs in a "MacroModel" namespace to indicate that they're going to be used in macros.)

Unfortunately, the code is proprietary, so I can't point you to it, but I can offer some suggestions on how to write it.

1. Use two phases: a Parser that looks through the string to figure out which types of operations are happening, and then an evaluator that uses the parsing results to produce a result given an object.
2. Use a state-machine architecture for your parser. Don't try to do the parsing all in one big function.
3. Unit test the crap out of it. This is *exactly* the sort of situation where Test-Driven Development really shines.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need too much this can work for you:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace t1
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        public string Prop {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public List<int> list = new List<int>() {1,2,3};
    }

    class SomeAnotherClass
    {
        public SomeClass Obj {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static object GetDynamic(object o, string query) {
            var elems = query.Split ('.');
            var current = o;
            var indexer = new Regex (@"(\w+)\[(\d+)\]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            foreach (var elem in elems)
            {
                var type = current.GetType ();
                var m = indexer.Match (elem);
                var memberName = elem;
                int? index = null;
                if (m.Success) {
                    memberName = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    index = int.Parse(m.Groups [2].Value);
                }

                var field = type.GetField (memberName);
                var prop = type.GetProperty (memberName);
                if (field != null)
                    current = field.GetValue (current);
                else if (prop != null)
                    current = prop.GetValue (current, null);
                else
                    throw new Exception ();

                if (index.HasValue)
                {
                    current = ((dynamic)current) [index.Value];
                }
            }
            return current;
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            object o = new SomeAnotherClass ()
            {
                Obj = new SomeClass()
                {
                    Prop = "asd"
                }
            };
            Console.WriteLine (GetDynamic(o, "Obj.list[1]"));

        }
    }
}
```